# Performance benefits between Single vs MultiValue Converter in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, converters

I am well aware of the usage of converters in wpf. However I am not sure of using one over other in a specific case.

I have a converter which use(for some weird reason) four properties of an object. Now either I could use a multi value converter and pass these four values in binding or I could use a single value converter and pass the whole object.

Which is better approach passing four integer values or passing a whole bulky object which is having around 10 to 15 properties in it.

Comment: You're only passing an object reference, so it doesn't matter how much properties the object has in total. You would have one Binding, compared to four Bindings plus the MultiBinding. The single binding to whole object approach is certainly more efficient.

Comment: It may however be difficult to get the single binding triggered when only one of the properties changes, but not the whole object. So in case of changing properties on always the same object instance, the single binding approach won't work.

Comment: @Clemens Every property on that object raise the Notification using INotifyPropertyChanged interface and I guess it should cover that problem.

Comment: When you bind directly to the object, that binding won't be triggered by any of the property changes.

Comment: @Clemens Yeah, I learn that hard way, rolling back the code to multi value converter.